# Pyspark: Read data from AWS:S3 bucket and write to postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read data from S3 bucket and want to write/ load it to postgres table. My code is as-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Read Multiple CSV Files').getOrCreate()
path = ['C://Projects/Sandbox/file2.csv']
files = spark.read.csv(path, sep=',',inferSchema=True, header=True)
df1 = files.toPandas()

from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(df1)

mode = "overwrite"
url = ""
properties = {"user": "","password": "","driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
my_writer.write.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

on line

```
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(files)
```

It gives error as-

> AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'write'

On line, when parameter to DataFrameWriter() is passed as -

```
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(df1)
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sql_ctx'

Is there anything/anywhere which I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution is correct

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Read Multiple CSV Files').getOrCreate()
path = ['C://Projects/Sandbox/file2.csv']
files = spark.read.csv(path, sep=',',inferSchema=True, header=True)
df1 = files.toPandas()

from pyspark.sql import DataFrameWriter
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(df1)

mode = "overwrite"
url = ""
properties = {"user": "","password": "","driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}
my_writer.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new instance of `DataFrameWriter`, spark dataframe already expose this interface using the `write` attribute. You can use this attribute to export the csv data using `jdbc` connection

```
# Read the data form source
files = spark.read.csv(path, sep=',', inferSchema=True, header=True)

# Write the data to destination using jdbc connection
files.write.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

---

How to fix your existing code?

Create a new instance of `DataFrameWriter` using **`files`** then use **`my_writer.jdbc`** to export the data using `jdbc` connection

```
my_writer = DataFrameWriter(files)
my_writer.jdbc(url=url, table="test_result", mode=mode, properties=properties)
#      ^^^^^^ No need to use .write attribute
```